# Why did the Dursleys hope that Harry would drown?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, when Harry was thinking about the 2nd Task of the Triwizard Tournament, he remembered that the Dursleys didn’t give him any swimming lessons when he was younger, hoping that Harry would drown.

Wasn’t Petunia, of all people, ever concerned about Harry drowning since she KNEW that Harry is prophecised to defeat Voldemort? Also, surely Harry would’ve got swimming lessons during PE at the Muggle primary school he went to?

Comment: I think it was more of a wistful longing. He is, after all, a terrible burden and hugely ungrateful.

Comment: Where does it say Petunia knew about Harry defeating Voldemort? As far as I can remember they only knew of Dumbledore's note which basically said "his parents were killed, treat him as your own kthxbye". Furthermore they're both so in denial of magic stuff that why would they feel complied to?

Comment: I never had swimming in primary school PE, and I lived in a coastal region? It is compulsory in the UK?

Comment: @Jenayah There was some compulsion going on in the Dursley's taking/keep Harry: *“You sent that Howler. You told her to remember — it was your voice —”
“I thought,” said Dumbledore, inclining his head slightly, “that she might need reminding of the pact she had sealed by taking you.*

Comment: @Skooba It is indeed mandated in the UK - only sport that is. And by age 11, so should apply to Harry. https://www.swimming.org/schools/swimming-national-curriculum/

Comment: @Valorum compulsory since 1994, so throughout the HP publishing history.

Comment: @Michael - OK, there's some nuance here. It's been mandatory for 25+ years, but from [1994 to 2012 only about 50% of schools actually met their statutory requirement](https://www.swimming.org/swimengland/curriculum-swimming/#:~:text=Swimming%20and%20water%20safety%20has,children%20meet%20the%20required%20standards). In very recent years it's been made a *non-optional* requirement, which means that schools can be sanctioned if they don't provide water safety. Harry could easily have gone to one of those 50% of schools that didn't provide swimming.

Comment: Also, this was  Harry's perception of what the Dursley's felt of him. Yes, they were never particularly fond of him, but I don't think they expressed wishing him dead?

Comment: @Jenayah I've [asked exactly that](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/249979/19561).

Comment: Also, I think that if someone were to put all of these comments together, they would have a half-decent answer at the very least.

Comment: @Michael, don't forget that the HP novels were set at least 7 years before their publication date. Harry started at Hogwarts in 1991.  His primary education was a few years earlier still, thus  before compulsory swimming lessons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the text of the passage in Chapter Twenty-Five of *Goblet of Fire*:

> He wasn’t a very good swimmer; he’d never had much practice. Dudley had had lessons in his youth, but Aunt Petunia and Uncle Vernon, no doubt hoping that Harry would drown one day, hadn’t bothered to give him any.

The implication here seems to be that the lessons (for Dudley) and lack thereof (for Harry) were private. One could surmise, then, that swimming lessons were not offered at school, or that not all students participated.

Regarding Petunia, as I argued [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/249979/how-much-did-petunia-dursley-know-about-the-circumstances-surrounding-the-death/250006#250006) she presumably was unaware of the prophecy concerning Harry. Moreover, her general practice was to pay no heed to the happenings in the Wizarding World, and to try to pretend that it didn’t exist.

In point of fact, though, she probably did not particularly want Harry to die. She kept her deal with Dumbledore which gave Harry the necessary protection to keep him alive. Had she wanted him dead she could have quit at any time.

(Veering somewhat into guesswork, I would compare Petunia to Snape in how they related to Harry.  Despite everything that happened, I think that Petunia still loved Lilly but just hated that the Wizarding World had stolen her. Harry thus represents conflicting feelings. On the one hand, he is her sister’s son who should therefore be loved, but on the other hand he is the continuation of the magic that broke them up in the first place. The not-quite-elegant solution is to protect his life, but try to stamp out the magic and treat him somewhat miserably. This is similar to how Snape protects Harry out of his love for Lilly, but bullies him out of his hatred for James. #conflictedcharacters )

Another thing to keep in mind is that the passage cited above is not a statement of an omniscient narrator, but is merely Harry’s bathtime musings. Musings of this sort do not always reflect accuracy even without other factors involved. In this case, though, Harry knows very little about his aunt and her relationship with Lilly. At this point in the story he also knows nothing about the prophecy. It may thus even be reasonable, from his experiences, to conclude that his aunt would want him to perish in an accident, even if objectively that is not actually the case.